# What are all the Waypoints in Act 1?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a list of waypoints?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67852/is-there-a-list-of-waypoints)

I just successfully completed the first Act, and I'm trying to see if I missed any. Unfortunately, unlike Diablo 2 there doesn't seem to be an in-game list I can check that would clue me in to ones I might be missing.

Comment: Roughly, how long did act 1 take to complete?

Comment: @Foxtrot 3 hours for me.

Comment: @Foxtrot 3-4 Hours for me.

Comment: Closing because I'd rather not get four different questions for each act

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Tristram
>
>   - New Tristram
>   - Old Ruins
> - The Cathedral
>
>   - Cathedral Garden
>   - Cathedral Level 3
>   - Royal Crypts
>   - Desolate Chamber
> - The Cemetery
>
>   - Cemetery of the Forsaken
> - The Fields
>
>   - The Fields of Misery
>   - Drowned Temple
>   - The Festering Woods
> - The Highlands
>
>   - Wortham Chapel Cellar
>   - Highlands Crossing
>   - Northern Highlands
>   - Leorics Mirror
> - The Halls of Agony
>
>   - Halls of Agony Level 2
>   - Halls of Agony Level 3

— from [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bt9kN-tu-M)