# Where are all the waypoints?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there a list of waypoints in Diablo 3?  I seem to be going long periods without finding one, and end up wondering whether there are any in the zones I'm passing through or if I'm just missing them, so I was looking for a list to check against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image linked to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k43af.jpg) is probably datamined from the beta, so looks to be quite out of date or just wrong, e.g. it mentions a non-existent Tower of the Damned Level 3 (there is no third level to the Tower of the Damned), is missing the Drowned Temple and Festering Woods waypoints from Act I and the Great Span waypoint in Act IV amongst others, and lists non-existant waypoints like Howling Plateau, etc (I searched for these across multiple zone reloads).

[This site](http://au.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Waypoints) appears to have a much more accurate list.  I've since cross-referenced waypoints as best I can, and have verified the below to the extant possible - confirming all my waypoints appear in my list, multiple runs through various zones where no waypoint is listed (focusing on those where the image indicates there could be one), etc.

> **Act I Waypoints**
>
> *TRISTRAM*
>
> - New Tristram
> - The Old Ruins
>
> *THE CATHEDRAL*
>
> - Cathedral Garden
> - Cathedral Level 3
> - The Royal Crypts
> - Desolate Chamber
>
> *THE CEMETERY*
>
> - Cemetery of the Forsaken
>
> *THE FIELDS*
>
> - Fields of Misery
> - Drowned Temple
> - The Festering Woods
>
> *THE HIGHLANDS*
>
> - Wortham Chapel Cellar
> - Highlands Crossing
> - Northern Highlands
> - Leoric's Manor
>
> *THE HALLS OF AGONY*
>
> - Halls of Agony Level 2
> - Halls of Agony Level 3
>
> **Act II Waypoints**
>
> *CALDEUM*
>
> - Hidden Camp
> - Sewers of Caldeum
>
> *STINGING WINDS*
>
> - Black Canyon Mines
> - Khasim Outpost
> - Road to Alcarnus
>
> *DAHLGUR OASIS*
>
> - Path to the Oasis
> - Dahlgur Oasis
>
> *DESOLATE SANDS*
>
> - Ancient Path
> - Desolate Sands
>
> *ARCHIVES OF ZOLTUN KULLE*
>
> - Archives of Zoltun Kulle
>
> **Act III Waypoints**
>
> *BASTION'S KEEP*
>
> - Bastion's Keep Stronghold
> - Stonefort
>
> *DEPTHS OF THE KEEP*
>
> - The Keep Depths Level 1
> - The Keep Depths Level 3
>
> *FIELDS OF SLAUGHTER*
>
> - The Bridge of Korsikk
> - Rakkis Crossing
>
> *ARREAT CRATER*
>
> - Arreat Crater Level 1
> - Tower of the Damned Level 1
> - Arreat Crater Level 2
> - Tower of the Cursed Level 1
> - The Core of Arreat
>
> **Act IV Waypoints**
>
> *BASTION'S KEEP*
>
> - Bastion's Keep Stronghold
>
> *GARDENS OF HOPE*
>
> - The Diamond Gates
> - The Vestibule of Light
> - Gardens of Hope 1st Tier
> - Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier
>
> *SILVER SPIRE*
>
> - The Crystal Colonnade
> - The Great Span
> - The Pinnacle of Heaven

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list. Bear in mind that not all waypoints are [accessible all the time](http://www.diablowiki.net/Waypoint). Also massive spoilers.

[image: waypoint list]

> While waypoints must be reached through dungeon exploration to activate and add to the display list, not all waypoints are always available. Even for a player who has already completed an area.

Also...

> This is an intentional feature, as it prevents players from exploiting the waypoint and quest system to quickly "run" bosses and obtain better drops and the large experience and gold rewards from completing quests.

Comment: That list appears not to be complete.  For starters, it's missing the Great Span waypoint in Act 4.